# file to import not found. Import of other files works

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package, importerror

I have a really strange problem.

I want to import two files which are in the package `soap`. But Eclipse doesn't "see" the files if I want to import them. Even if I change the directory of the file to a package, in which Eclipse sees the other files and is able to import them, these two new .java-files won't show up to import. Even if I try to import it "by-hand", Eclipse doesn't find them:

```
import ch.asdf.soap.DocumentReply;
import ch.asdf.soap.DocumentRequest;
```

I've also tried to import the whole package:

```
import ch.asdf.soap.*;
```

There aren't any errors in the files.

Comment: I think while importing choose file type as *.*(means all file)....

Comment: I've edited my question. I've also tried that, doesnt work.

Comment: are the file where you are using import and the file to be imported in different packages?

Comment: @Subash Yes. They are in different "sub-projects". But for other files, it also works.

Comment: if they are on different packages then the private data and methods of the class cannot be used without getter and setter methods. I tried in my code it works for me

Comment: @Subash It's really strange. I think, Eclipse is buggy, because the whole file is really simple and public. There is no private method or data. So I think, Eclipse causes the problem.

Comment: try netbeans for a change

Comment: I can't because I'm at work and can only use Eclipse. I will try to use another version of eclipse.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it, but it didn't help.